# I am trying to find the square root of a number but for some reason, it finds my variable as a string, while at the same time it finds it as a float

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, math

I am making a scientific calculator(this is a test, not my source code, I wanted to test and see if I'd still get the same error(I did)). If for example I input a number x and press the square root button, my program crashes and it shows the following error: Exception thrown 'str' object has no attribute 'sqrt'. Both my num_1 and f_num register as float and get values assigned to them, and i know that because i am using visual studio and when i hover over those variables it will highlight that both are float, and the value assigned(i.e. 256). Sorry if my explanation is bad, I am a novice programmer with little to no knowledge of python and its also my first time trying to build a GUI. Thank you in advance.

```
import math 
from tkinter import *




def sqrt(first_number):
    global math
    global f_num
    math="sqrt"
    f_num=float(first_number)

def button_equal(second_number):
    num_1=f_num
    
    if math == "sqrt":
     Panel.delete(0, END)
     Panel.insert(0, math.sqrt(num_1))

def button_click(number):
    # Panel.delete(0, END)
    Panel.insert(0, number)

root = Tk()
root.title("scientific calculator")
root.resizable(width=False, height = False)
root.geometry("400x492+460+40")

myButton = Button(root, text="1",padx=3)
MainFrame = Frame( root, bd=20, pady=2, relief = RIDGE).grid()

Panel = Entry(root, font=("default", 20), bd=2, justify="right")
Panel.place(height=100, width=327, x=3,y=25)  # The width of the panel is the value of the x axis on root.geometry - 3px on each side for margin
Panel.insert(0, "0")

B17 = Button(root, font=("default", 15), fg="orange", bg="#696969", text="1", command=lambda: button_click(1))
B17.place(width=75, height=50, x=8, y=330)
B18 = Button(root, font=("default", 15), fg="orange", bg="#696969", text="2", command=lambda: button_click(2))
B18.place(width=75, height=50, x=87, y=330)
B19 = Button(root, font=("default", 15), fg="orange", bg="#696969", text="3", command=lambda: button_click(3))
B19.place(width=75, height=50, x=167, y=330)
B6 = Button(root, font=("default", 15), fg="orange", bg="#696969", text="x^", command=lambda: sqrt(Panel.get()))
B6.place(width=75, height=50, x=87, y=180)
B24 = Button(root, font=("default", 15), fg="orange", bg="#696969", text="=", command=lambda: button_equal(Panel.get()))
B24.place(width=75, height=50, x=245, y=380)

calc = Frame( MainFrame, bd=20, pady=2, relief = RIDGE).grid() 

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried initializing the functions in different ways, for example I tried forcing the type of variables even though I theoretically don't need to, since python does that by herself. I've also tried initializing the math function inside my first_number function and again nothing. Generally speaking, whatever I tried failed, so after a while I am not sure if its a programming or logical error. Even though, I lean on the theory that it's a logical error because I've also tried other compilers but with no avail.

Comment: Why are you importing the math module and then overwriting the name with the string 'sqrt'?

Comment: The `.get()` method of the `Entry` widget class returns a string. If you want these values to be interpreted as numbers, you can cast them to floats with `float(f_num)` (for example)

Comment: @jprebys because if I don't python says math is not defined. But indeed, you are correct, It did overwrite it self as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared math as a variable as well as a package. Python is confused. rename your global variable called math (or remove the global variable altogether)

You get the error since you set math to a string.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, since this is my thesis and technically you gave me the answer, I would like to credit you as a source, if that's okay with you